# How to filter NSArray using predicate on an object property

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  [self.map removeAnnotations:self.map.annotations];
  if ([textField isEqual:self.searchText]) {
      NSPredicate *bPredicate = 
      [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c],  %@",self.searchText.text];

      self.filteredArray = [self.hotelArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
      NSLog(@" HEARE %@",self.filteredArray);
      [self markAllHotels];
  }
  return YES;
}
```

`hotelArray` and `filteredArray` are `NSArray`s.

`hotelArray` has objects of type `hotel` where `hotel` has a property `name`.

Problem : 
I want to filter `hotelArray` according to `hotel.name` when `hotel.name` matches text entered in `searchText` [text field], but I am getting an empty `self.filteredArray`.

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473973/nspredicate-case-insensitive-matching-on-to-many-relationship

Comment: Your question is missing. What problems do you exactly have with your posted code?

Comment: @Vishwa Patel that code is not working for me . using ANY is crashing the simulator.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try following lines, and make sure `properyName` is case sensitive. and you have placed `,` in predicate format, thats why its not working. just replace your code with following.

**Objective C**

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[cd] %@",self.searchText.text];
self.filteredArray = [self.hotelArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
NSLog(@"HERE %@",self.filteredArray);
```

**Swift**

```
var bPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name contains[cd] %@", self.searchText.text)
self.filteredArray = self.hotelArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(bPredicate)
NSLog("HERE %@", self.filteredArray)
```

**Using swift `filter`**

```
var searchText = "Galaxy"

let filteredArray = hotelArray.filter { $0["name"] == searchText }
print("** Result ** \n\(filteredArray)")
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let arrEmp = [["name": "James", "age" : 27, "city" : "New york"],
                   ["name": "Johnson", "age" : 24, "city" : "London"],
                   ["name": "Alex", "age" : 28, "city" : "Newark"],
                   ["name": "Mark", "age" : 25, "city" : "Paris"],
                   ["name": "Steve", "age" : 25, "city" : "Silicon Valley"],
                   ["name": "Lary", "age" : 28, "city" : "New york"]]

// *** Filter by Name exact match ***
var filterByName = arrEmp.filter { $0["name"] == "Mark" }
print("filterByName \(filterByName)")

// *** Filter by Age ***
var filterByAge = arrEmp.filter { $0["age"] as! Int >  25 }
print("filterByAge \(filterByAge)")
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
var filterByName = arrEmp.filter
do {
    $0["name"] == "Mark"
}
print("filterByName filterByName)")

var filterByAge = arrEmp.filter
do {
    $0["age"] as! Int > 25
}
print("filterByAge filterByAge)")
```

Comment: [NSString "sometext%i",4] IOS makes it number not string that was the error .

Comment: @Anz are you filtering array of dictionary? Given code is tested on Swift 3.0

Comment: @DipenPanchasara Yes it is

Comment: You can post a question with your data and other information, then one can provide solution

Answer (score 5):

Based on your information, this is your situation:

```
self.hotelArray      // Array in which we perform a search
self.filteredArray   // Result array
name                 // Property of the object used for the predicate
```

This predicate should work for you:

```
NSString *searchText = self.searchText.text;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.name contains[c] %@", searchText];
self.filteredArray = [self.hotelArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this library

https://github.com/BadChoice/Collection

It comes with lots of easy array functions to never write a loop again

So you can just do:

```
NSArray* hotels = [self.hotelArray filter:^BOOL(Hotel *hotel) {
    [return hotel.name isEqualToString:searchText];
}];
```

or simply

```
NSArray* hotels = [self.hotelArray where:@"name" is:searchText];
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

This is the predicate method that might work for you.

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [filteredContactArray removeAllObjects];

    NSArray *tempArray = [hotelArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@ OR name contains[cd] %@",searchText]];

    filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];//if you want the filtered array to be mutable or tempArray will work as as desired by you.
}
```

contains[c]- means the predicate with case sensitive.
contains[cd]- case insensitive string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to do :

```
-(NSArray*)searchString:(NSString*)stringToSearch inArray:(NSArray*)myArray
{
    NSMutableArray* filtredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString* elmnt in myArray)
    {
        if ([elmnt rangeOfString:stringToSearch].location != NSNotFound) [fitredArray addObject:elmnt];
    }
    return filtredArray;
}
```

Comment: i don't wanna loop through elements.

Comment: i wanna use filteredArrayUsingPredicate or something similar