# Filter NSMutableDiction with Key

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nspredicate

I need to filter this NSMutableDictionary on key value based where `item_type= bad`

i tried but not working

```
 NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(item_type == %@)", @"Good"];

    NSArray *resultArray = [[dummyDictionary allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

    NSLog(@"resultArray:%@",resultArray);





{
    “Cat1” =     (
                {
            "image_item" = “a”;
            "item_type" = “Good”;
                  }
    );
    Cat2 =     (
                {
            "image_item" = “b”;
            "item_type" = Good;
                 },
                {
            "image_item" = “c”;
            "item_type" = Bad;
              },

    );
    Cat3 =     (
                {
            "image_item" = “d”;
            "item_type" = Good;
                 },
                {
            "image_item" = “e”;
            "item_type" = Bad;
                  },
       );
  }
```

**And need such output NSMutableDictionary**

```
{
    “Cat1” =     (

    );
    Cat2 =     (

                {
            "image_item" = “c”;
            "item_type" = Bad;
              },

    );
    Cat3 =     (

                {
            "image_item" = “e”;
            "item_type" = Bad;
                  },
       );
  }
```

**NOTE: dummyDictionary is value i get from .plist**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter NSArray using predicate on an object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676371/how-to-filter-nsarray-using-predicate-on-an-object-property)

Comment: I'm not sure that `NSPredicate` "alone" would work. By the way, is the NSArray (values from inside your dict) are mutable? Do you want a copy of that? I'd suggest to do it manually for each array (with the NSPredicate).

Comment: simply working with array , filter work but i need dictionary in the same patern