# How to use NSPredicate for searching an item from an array of dictionaries inside an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nspredicate

I have a list of objects. Each object has a number of properties including an array of dictionaries called 'members'. And each member has a name along with other properties. I want to search for an item which has 'members' containing keys with the same values or simply the same members.

How can I use NSPredicate to search for that?

Thank you for your time and feedback

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: [Possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19676711/886926)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SUBQUERY:

```
NSPredicate.init(format: "SUBQUERY(routes, $route, $route.transferCount <= %@).@count == routes.@count", self.numberOfTransfersValue())
```

Comment: I don't see any relevance of what you have written to what I asked

Comment: Thank you for your time anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText];

NSArray * searchResult = [nameArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```